# Remove a column from a nested list in Python

Tags: python, list

I need help figuring how to work around removing a 'column' from a nested list to modify it.

Say I have

```
L = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,1,2,3]]
```

and I want to remove the second column (so values 2,6,1) to get:

```
L = [[1,3,4],
     [5,7,8],
     [9,2,3]]
```

I'm stuck with how to modify the list with just taking out a column. I've done something sort of like this before? Except we were printing it instead, and of course it wouldn't work in this case because I believe the break conflicts with the rest of the values I want in the list.

```
def L_break(L):

i = 0
while i < len(L):
    k = 0
    while k < len(L[i]):
        print( L[i][k] , end = " ")
        if k == 1:
            break
        k = k + 1
    print()
    i = i + 1
```

So, how would you go about modifying this nested list?
Is my mind in the right place comparing it to the code I have posted or does this require something different?

Answer (score 25):

You can simply delete the appropriate element from each row using [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement):

```
L = [[1,2,3,4],
     [5,6,7,8],
     [9,1,2,3]]

for row in L:
    del row[1]  # 0 for column 1, 1 for column 2, etc.

print L
# outputs [[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Ok so obviously I've still much to get out of python; what exactly is 'row' ? Like, is it something that's built in python? I've never used it before

Comment: @Crisis All we're doing here is looping over the list `L`. We assign the variable (arbitrarily named) `row` to each element of `L` (i.e. each nested list). Then, we delete an element of `row` using `del`. You might want to read about Python basics such as for-loops.

Comment: @arashajii Oh ok ok, right I think I understand. My instructor does not want us to use For-loops yet so I wasn't sure. Thank-you.

Comment: working for me. row is just the actual iterative element in the row. It is like the common i in c++ for (int i =0; i < 10; i++){}

Answer (score 11):

If you want to *extract* that column for later use, while removing it from the original list, use a list comprehension with `pop`:

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3,4],
...       [5,6,7,8],
...       [9,1,2,3]]
>>> 
>>> [r.pop(1) for r in L]
[2, 6, 1]
>>> L
[[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 2, 3]]
```

Otherwise, just loop over the list and delete the fields you no longer want, as in [arshajii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800048/418413)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), which is created for this very purpose.

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter(0, 2, 3)            # Only indexes which are needed
print(list(map(list, map(getter, L))))
# [[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 2, 3]]
```

You can use it in List comprehension like this

```
print([list(getter(item)) for item in L])
# [[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 2, 3]]
```

You can also use nested List Comprehension, in which we skip the elements if the index is 1, like this

```
print([[item for index, item in enumerate(items) if index != 1] for items in L])
# [[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 2, 3]]
```

**Note:** All these suggested in this answer will not affect the original list. They will generate new lists without the unwanted elements.

Answer (score 6):

Use `map-lambda`:

```
print map(lambda x: x[:1]+x[2:], L)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, updated to take in kojiro's advice.

```
>>> L[:] = [i[:1]+i[2:] for i in L]
>>> L
[[1, 3, 4], [5, 7, 8], [9, 2, 3]]
```

You can generalize this to remove any column:

```
def remove_column(matrix, column):
    return [row[:column] + row[column+1:] for row in matrix]

# Remove 2nd column
copyofL = remove_column(L, 1) # Column is zero-base, so, 1=second column
```

Comment: You may wish to have `L[:]` on the LHS of that expression to replace the list in-place.

Answer (score 1):

when you do the **del** it will delete that index and reset the index, so you have to reduce that index. Here I use the count to reduce and reset the same from the index list we have. Hope this helps. Thanks

```
nested_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
remove_cols_index = [1,2]

count = 0
for i in remove_cols_index:
    i = i-count
    count = count+1

    del nested_list[i]

print (nested_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[j.pop(1) for j in nested_list]
```

from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-column-deletion-from-list-of-lists/

Comment: Admittedly this is neither an unappreciated link-only answer nor an unappreciated code-only answer, but you should definitly explain how this works and why it is supposed to help. People with the voting privilege just like explained answers better...