# Python: Populating an empty list of lists from a larger list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists f:

```
f= [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
```

and I want to populate an empty list,

`new_list = []`, with columns 1 & 3 from f.

When I try:

```
for row in f:
    new_list.append(row[0])
    new_list.append(row[2])
```

I get the result:

```
new_list = [1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12]
```

But what I want is:

```
new_list = [[1,3],[4,6],[7,9],[10,12]]
```

I am new to python. What is the simplest way this can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove a column from a nested list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800028/remove-a-column-from-a-nested-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
new_list = [i[::2] for i in f]
```

And now:

```
print(new_list)
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [10, 12]]
```

You have to iterate trough the list, get access to every sublist, after that all we need to do is get the every second element, but if you just want zeroth and second, do:

```
new_list = [[i[0],i[2]] for i in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for row in f:
    new_list.append(row[0])
    new_list.append(row[2])
```

use:

```
for row in f:
    nested_list = [row[0], row[2]]
    new_list.append(nested_list)
```

For sure, answer from @U9-Forward is better if you know how to use list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
new_list = f
for col in new_list :
    del col[1]
```

this will output as

```
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9], [10, 12]]
```